# Programming by Interfaces

Tags: java, interface

When in interface you declare a method that takes an interface as an argument like

```
public interface testInterface{
  public void TestMethod(SomeInterface in);

}
```

When you get to implement this method in a class that implements this interface, does the argument need to be again `(SomeInterface in)`(most general form) or can it be just an interface that implements `SomeInterface`? If the first holds, do I need to cast or what?

**Update**: I mean if the method signature in the implementing class must have `(SomeInterface in)` as a parameter or if it can be a specific class implementing `(SomeInterface in)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I mean if the method signature in the implementing class must have (`SomeInterface in`) as a parameter or if it can be a specific class implementing (`SomeInterface in`)

No, the method signature must accept the interface. This fails, for instance:

```
interface FooInterface {
    public void doSomething();
}

class Foo implements FooInterface {
    public void doSomething() { }
}

interface BarInterface {
    public void myMethod(FooInterface f);
}

class Bar implements BarInterface {
    public void myMethod(Foo f) { }
    //                   ^----------------- Note
}
```

If you try to compile that, you get:

```
Bar is not abstract and does not override abstract method myMethod(FooInterface) in BarInterface
    class Bar implements BarInterface {
```

But if you define `Bar.myMethod` as accepting `FooInterface`, you can (of course) call it with `Foo` instances, as that's the point of interfaces.

Comment: To whoever it was who kept trying to fix this for me but I kept overlapping with: Thank you. Such a silly, crucial, typo.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to cast; you can pass *any* subclass of your argument as a parameter.

Otherwise, `Object's` [`.equals()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals-java.lang.Object-) would never work! It accepts an `Object` as an argument, but you can do `"foo".equals("bar")`.

And anyway, you cannot build a new instance of an interface (except if you create an anonymous class). You have to provide an implementation...

Answer (score 1):

In place of `SomeInterface in` you can pass any Class that implements SomeInterface.

Answer (score 1):

As long as the instance you pass into the method `TestMethod` implements `SomeInterface` or another interface which extends `SomeInterface` you are fine. Besides, methods in Java should start lowercase. Instead of casting you may us generics like this:

```
public interface TestInterface<T extends SomeInterface> {
    public void testMethod(T in);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can pass the references of the class that implements the SomeInterface as the arguments.

like

```
class test implements SomeInterface{

SomeInterface in=new test();
public void TestMethod(in );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can precisate 3 parts of a interface-method-declaration

- Return type (impl's type must inherit interface's type)
- Exception type (interface's type must inherit impl's type or impl's type must inherit interface's type)
- Parameter types (impl's type must inherit interface's type)

Example:

```
interface Test {
    Number test(CharSequence v) throws IllegalArgumentException;
}
```

Impl:

```
public class TestImpl implements Test {
    public Integer test(final String v) throws NumberFormatException {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Note:

**Parameters using `...`-arrays can inherit `[]`-arrays.**